# Canvas figure not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am fairly new to Python. I have written the following code that is supposed to show an embedded plot when the "Plot" button is pressed. The code runs without any errors; However I get no figures. I should add that the Plotter class intentionally has two methods of plot_figure and show_plot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = Figure()

    def plot_figure(self):
        self.figarray = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.figarray.plot((1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4))
        return self.f

    def show_plot(self):
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, root )
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)


plot1 = Plotter()
button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Plot', command=plot1.show_plot)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)
Tk.mainloop()
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I get no figures"? Do you mean you get a grey area? Because that's what I get and that's simply because you never call `self.plot_figure` which actually creates the (sub)plot and plots the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you are trying to achieve here, but your plot_figure method is never called, hence there is no subplot to show and you only have an empty canvas.

If you call your method just before drawing the plot you will have your figures.

```
def show_plot(self):
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
    self.plot_figure()
    self.canvas.show()
    ...
```